# Weka and K-Means clustering - how to obtain the full data mean

Tags: classification, weka, k-means

I am using weka and although I can get the class means, I need to get Weka's full data mean. This doesn't seem to have been done through getting clas means adding them up and then dividing by the number of classes, as the full data mean varies quite a lot from this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the direct calculation isn't too hard, but I'm not familiar with WEKA, so I suggest a roundabout route: how about running the k-means clustering with just one cluster (`k=1`)? That cluster will contain all the data points and the mean will therefore be the mean of the whole dataset. Or did you mean something different by the "full data mean"?

Answer (score 0):

On the Weka Explorer Preprocess tab, click on the data variable you loaded and you will see the mean and other statistics on the right hand side.